# How can I use kickstart or something else at the command line to view ARD settings?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, terminal.app, kickstart, apple-remote-desktop

I know I can use [`kickstart`](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2370) to configure Apple Remote Desktop from the command line, but, I can't find anything on the Internet or in `kickstart`'s help message indicating how I can view the current settings from the command line. Does anyone know where I can get these settings?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the manual:

```
man /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart
```

which reads:

```
sub Usage1 {
    qq{ kickstart -- Quickly uninstall, install, activate, configure, and/or restart
             components of Apple Remote Desktop without a reboot.

kickstart -uninstall -files -settings -prefs

      -install -package <path>

      -deactivate
      -activate

      -configure -users <user1,user2...>
        -access -on  -off
        -privs  -all -none
                -DeleteFiles
                -ControlObserve
                -TextMessages
                -ShowObserve
                -OpenQuitApps
                -GenerateReports
                -RestartShutDown
                -SendFiles
                -ChangeSettings
                -ObserveOnly
                -mask <mask>

        -allowAccessFor
                -allUsers [-privs <priv options>]
                -specifiedUsers

        -computerinfo -set1 -1 <text>
                      -set2 -2 <text>
                      -set3 -3 <text>
                      -set4 -4 <text>

        -clientopts
          -setmenuextra -menuextra  yes
```

Comment: So... Quickly reading the full output (the above is just a snippet) it seems there's no command to *"view the current settings"* as asked?